# Unable to pun Python scripts via Pypi package

Tags: python, pip, package, setup.py, pypi

I'm trying to publish a python package, and I'm having trouble getting it to run after installing it via `pip`. I believe this is due to my "entry_points" property in my setup.py file.

Currently I can download the project via `pip install my_package_name`. When I try to run the package I enter `my_package_name` and get a NameError saying `initialize() is not defined`. However, if I enter `python path/to/my_package_name/__main__.py` it runs just fine. Below is my project tree and my setup.py and __main__.py files for reference:

```
my_package_name/  
    setup.py  
    my_package_name/  
        __init__.py  
        __main__.py  
        my_package_name.py
```

---

`setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'my_package_name',
    version = '0.0.1',
    packages = ['my_package_name'],
    install_requires = ['this', 'that'],
    license = 'Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike license',
    description = 'My cool python package',
    long_description = open('readme.txt').read(),
    url = 'mypackagename.github.io',
    author = 'My Name',
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_package_name = my_package_name.__main__:main' # this is likely what I'm doing wrong
        ]
    },
)
```

---

`__main__.py`:

```
from my_package_name import *

def main(args=None):
    """The main routine."""
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    initialize()
    do_something()
    do_something_else()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If more info is needed please let me know. This is my first swing at python, so there might be a big, common-knowledge piece that I'm missing. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**
Here is the full error log when running `my_package_name`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\my_package_name-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('my_package_name==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'my_package_name')()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\my_package_name\__main__.py", line 12, in main
    initialize()
NameError: name 'initialize' is not defined
```

Comment: please add the full error traceback to your question

Comment: You have given the package and module the same name `my_package_name`. When running `python script.py`, the dir containing script is added to `sys.path`, so `initialize` is correctly imported from _module_ `my_package_name`. In other cases, the dir `path/to/my_package_name` is not in `sys.path`, so `initialize` is imported from _package_ `my_package_name` and is not found. You should be able to reproduce it by running e.g. `python -m my_package_name.__main__`.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for the info! For this example, I'm guessing editing my \_\_main\_\_.py file to include:
`from my_package_name.my_package_name import *` would be a solution (albeit sloppy?)